# Easiest way to isolate words starting with specific symbols from strings in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Let's say I have a string `Hey @eli check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com`

Ideally I want to turn this into an array like `[{type: 'text', content: 'Hey '}, {type: 'mention', content: '@eli'}, {type: 'text', content: ' check out this link: '}, {type: 'href', content: 'https://stackoverflow.com'}]` so I can add styles to or wrap certain strings of the text.

I am currently doing this with a series of .split()s, but it feels somewhat complex. Is there an easier way to isolate/break-up a string, based on trailing characters/strings?

Current solution for #s and @s:

```
const valueAsArray = []
    value.split(/\r?\n/).forEach((line) => {
      if (line) {
        const line_: Line[] = [];
        line.split(' ').forEach((space, i) => {
          space.split('@').forEach((mention, i) => {
            if (i === 0) {
              mention.split('#').forEach((hashtag, i) => {
                if (i === 0) {
                  line_.push({ type: 'text', content: hashtag });
                } else {
                  line_.push({ type: 'hashtag', content: `#${hashtag}` });
                }
              });
            } else {
              line_.push({ type: 'mention', content: `@${mention}` });
            }
          });
          line_.push({ type: 'text', content: ' ' });
        });
        valueAsArray.push({ type: 'line', content: line_ });
      } else {
        valueAsArray.push({ type: 'spacer' });
      }
    });
```

Comment: You might have better luck trying to identify an exact pattern you're looking for, then visiting regex101 to learn how to segment

Comment: @Kinglish Ok, I will look into regex segments. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I would just use regex for the entire keyword search, using the or pipe | separating the different keywords

```
const keys = /([@#]\S+|https\S+)/gi
```

@ *or* # + string of characters 
^ key 

https + string of characters 
^ another key

And then you would end up with an array like this:

1. ‘Hey ’
2. ‘@eli ‘
3. ‘check out this link: ‘
4. ‘https://stackoverflow.com ‘
5. ‘’ << *empty string*

   and then you can just check each item in the array for different things

```
const valueAsArray = [];
value.split(keys).forEach(item => {
    if (item[0] == '@' || item[0] == '#'){
        valueAsArray.push({
            type: 'mention',
            content: item
        });
    } else if (item.includes('https')){
        valueAsArray.push({
            type: 'href',
            content: item
        });
    } else {
        valueAsArray.push({
            type: 'text',
            content: item
        });
    }
});
```

Maybe there’s a more efficient way, but I thought this would probably be most flexible in your case. Hope this helps

Comment: I would recommend `startsWith('http')` instead of `includes`, and you might want to ignore the empty strings created by the splitting